# Resource not found for segment 'Property'

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

When using ADO.Net Data Services client to refresh an entity by calling the `LoadProperty`:

```
ctx.BeginLoadProperty(this, "Owner", (IAsyncResult ar) => ...
```

It throws an error on the server if the property is `null`

> Error: Exception Thrown: System.Data.Services.DataServiceException:
>   Resource not found for the segment 'Owner'.    at
>   System.Data.Services.RequestDescription.GetSingleResultFromEnumerable(SegmentInfo
>   segmentInfo)    at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService1.CompareETagAndWriteResponse(RequestDescription
>   description, ContentFormat responseFormat, IDataService dataService)
>   at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService1.SerializeResponseBody(RequestDescription
>   description, IDataService dataService)    at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService1.HandleNonBatchRequest(RequestDescription
>   description)    at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()

Problem is that the client does not know whether the property is `null` or just hasn't been populated yet.  The property Owner is a link from a `Vehicle` to a `Customer`.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Querying on primary keys generate an exception when the key does not exist. The workaround is to add a dummy true expression in the condition (eg : 1==1 && item.Id == XXX).

Without the dummy expression the ADO.NET request is:

> http: //localhost//test.svc/Role(XXX)

With the dummy condition, the request is:

> http: //localhost//test.svc/Role()?$filter=true and (Id eq 1)

The expected behaviour (null returned) is correct in the second case.

Comment: This [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505761/resource-not-found-for-segment-property/5987733#5987733) is a better option. Makes for more readable code.

Answer (score 33):

Set [IgnoreResourceNotFoundException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.ignoreresourcenotfoundexception.aspx) property of the service context to true:

```
svc.IgnoreResourceNotFoundException = true;
```

Comment: Note that this property was added in .NET 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 3):

I've received a "Resource not found for segment 'Property'" error also.  Mine appears to be that in the where clause I am looking by primary key.  I have found some resources that say it will throw an error (even when using FirstOrDefault()) when using a primary key that doesn't exist (as opposed to other where clauses that just do not provide results).  I'd guess a similar thing is happening to yourself.